# Is it possible to manual check the memory alignment in c?

Tags: c, memory-management, allocation

I use intrinsics so I need to use memory alignment.
By this reason I always code like:

```
float* data = (float*) _mm_malloc(sizeof(float)*3, 64);
```

But in some cases I have arrays with mixed content. So some parts are aligned and some not.

I tried to use simple test `data%64 == 0` but compiler throws `error: expression must have integral type`. Operation modulo is not supported for pointers.

Is it possible to implement function which works like this:

```
// prototype
int testAlignment(void *pointer, int alignment);

float* data = (float*) _mm_malloc(sizeof(float)*3, 64);
testAlignment(data, 64); // true
testAlignment(data + 1, 64); // false
```

Comment: `((uintptr_t)(void*)data)%64u == 0` works. Check it yourself.

Comment: I know the compiler will probably optimize this anyway, but `(((uintptr_t)(void*)data)&63u) == 0` might be a better way to describe alignment. *Sidenote*: `malloc` will return maximum alignment by default (on my 64bit machine, that would be 128bits due to the maximum integer type width the CPU handles).

Comment: @Myst: Do you realize your sidenote is irrelevant, when we are talking about intrinsics? `malloc()` alignment is not sufficient for vector types.

Comment: @NominalAnimal 64 bit alignment might not be sufficient for some vector types, but it **is** the alignment in the example... ;)

Comment: @Myst I work with AVX512 and in my example alignment is in bytes.

Comment: Oh, right, my bad... got confused for a moment :-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` operator needs *integer* operands. So how to convert a pointer to an *integer*?

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. ..., the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined.  C11 §6.3.2.3 5

Consider the below, the conversion of a `float *` to an `unsigned` likely will work, yet it risks undefined behavior (UB).

```
float* data = foo();
if ((unsigned)data % 64 == 0) puts("aligned 64");
```

---

Can we do better?

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. §6.3.2.3 1
>
> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type ... `uintptr_t` ...
>   These types are optional §7.20.1.4 1

Yes, by converting to `void*` and then to `uintptr_t`, code avoids UB [@coderredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48976874/is-it-possible-to-manual-check-the-memory-alignment-in-c/48979301#comment84958677_48976874).  Still `uintptr_t` is an *optional* type.  Yet rarely is it unavailable since C99.

```
#include <stdint.h>
if ((uintptr_t)(void*)data % 64 == 0) puts("aligned 64");
```

Answer (score -2):

Reminder operation is not defined for pointers, but you can cast the pointer to integer.

```
((unsigned)data % 64) == 0
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Look at coderredoc's comment to see why it was up-voted and this was down-voted.  Then steal his answer to update yours - he should have posted an answer rather then a comment in any case.

Comment: @Clifford - Exactly what do you want me to steal? That unnecessary cast to void*? I don't think it will improve the answer. Replacing % with & may be a better idea, bit it is pure aesthetic anyway - the compiler always optimizes division to power of two.

Comment: The cast to `void*` is not strictly unnecessary, it is the only pointer type for which `uintptr_t` is defined, and `uintptr_t` is necessary because `unsigned` may not be large enough to hold a pointer - typically so on 64 bit and 16 bit systems.  Possibly that does not matter since only the last 6 bits are of interest.  It is academic now, @chux has posted that answer.  You had the right idea, but got downvoted through lack of rigour.  I was hoping to save you from that.

Comment: You might perhaps add information to justify why this will work on any platform, but the UB police will downvote it regardless, and avoiding it is straightforward.

Comment: Personally I like the `&` idea in preference to `%`.  In other cases you might have a variable alignment test, which might not be trivially optimised.

Comment: @Clifford - I did consider casting to ULONG_PTR (yes, I know, but uintptr_t is not portable either), but decided that truncating to 32 bits will result to more efficient and portable code. And no, I don't want to edit a perfectly correct answer just because some people downvote anything that does not fit their scholastic view of programming style. Anyway, thanks for understanding.

Comment: §6.3.2.3 5 is not applicable here as it says something different. It refers to a hypothetical case of pointers that cannot be represented by integers. And in that hypothetical case of UB no cast will work properly - be it (uintptr_t)(void*) or just (unsigned).